# Delphi - Reverse Lookup ' who includes this unit'

Tags: delphi

I am debugging a large application distributed over many units.
I ran into a compilation error in a low level unit and do not have the slightest idea in which part of the application this unit is referenced. Is there a way to use RAD studio 2010's IDE to create some kind of include-graph?

As most of the units used are not part of the project  and spread over quite a branchy source tree, i can not simply use the 'find in files' option.

I am currently traversing through my tree using a search-in-files-utility, but this is cumbersome.

Do you know of  amore elegant way? 
Development is in Embercadero RAD studio 2010, windows XP 32.

Comment: Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731799/how-can-i-find-all-the-units-in-my-delphi-app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [Modelmaker's unit dependeny analyzer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/articles/unit-dependencies.html). This may give you more than you want and its free.

Comment: Thank you for the link. For what it's worth,  if I hadn't already seleted an answer, you would get the credit.

Comment: [META Ha, I can change my selected answer. Good for you

Comment: +1; Also make sure you take a look at MMX (Modelmaker Code Explorer http://bit.ly/9r1qaV): it is great! I use it for every Delphi project. It makes me so much more productive, without ever getting in my way.

Comment: +1 for the MMX suggestion. It is the first thing to install after installing Delphi/RAD Studio. Cannot live without it. And it includes the dependency analyzer.

Answer (score 7):

I use very simple idea: I rename unit name from .pas to .pas_ and then build project. Compiler will report error in unit that uses the unit you are looking for. Simple and work very well but I will not name it "elegant" :(

I think Delphi instead of:

```
[Pascal Fatal Error] unit2.pas(31): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'unit2'
```

should report:

```
[Pascal Fatal Error] unit2.pas(31): F2063 Could not compile unit 'unit2' used by 'unit1'
```

(maybe some of Delphi maintainers read it: it will make our lives easier)

Answer (score 3):

[Peganza's Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.htm) has an "Uses Report". Maybe this can help you.

Edit: You might also want to check out Icarus from the same company. It's free (as in beer :-)) (credits to Uwe).

Comment: Icarus from Peganza only does the uses thing and is free.