# Tools to generate unit dependencies for Delphi

Tags: delphi, dependencies, conditional-compilation

Are there any tools that can generate dependency diagrams for Delphi units taking into account conditional compilation directives. I'd like to emphasize that this should be unit dependency diagram, not class dependency. Also it would be nice to have the ability to rearrange and hide some parts in the generated diagram.

I've tried [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/) and it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally use the **free [Project Dependencies](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?project_dependencies.html) from [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org)**.
It does not display a diagram, but as a tree view. That suits my needs, YMMV.

Comment: Does that copy all the files that the project needs to a given directory?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [ICARUS](http://www.peganza.com/#ICARUS) is helpful.

Comment: From the description it seems that it helps to remove unused units. Can it show dependencies?

Comment: The full peganza used to do this. It would list the full dependency graph. Could not see if current version does. Maybe email and ask

Answer (score 3):

See this related question, where Peganza was discussed.
[Tool that shows unit dependencies for Delphi 2010 or Delphi 7 program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904011/tool-that-shows-unit-dependencies-for-delphi-2010-or-delphi-7-program/2904397#2904397)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Delphi Unit Dependency Scanner from https://github.com/norgepaul/DUDS and export the tree in Gephi or yEd format.

Then you can build the graph, analyze and do many other actions with the graph using the open source tool from https://gephi.org/ or free https://www.yworks.com/products/yed.

Comment: @Kromster: thanks for the edit, I also use the yEd already for a long time :)

Comment: yEd is awesome and that's why I have asked DUDS developer to add support for it and gave him the export code :-D

Comment: @Kromster and I asked them for Gephi :D So we have our 2 buttons here :)

Answer (score 2):

I use ModelMakers [Unit Dependency Analyzer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/articles/unit-dependencies.html) together with [Lattix LDM](http://www.lattix.com/products/ldm-ldv).

Answer (score 0):

The open source pascal code documentation tool [PasDoc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pasdoc/) can do that too