# How do I view the hierarchy of which Unit USES another? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, include, hierarchy, uses-clause

There is a large project, and I need to see the hierarchy of Units which each file references in it's USES clause.

ex.

```
                                Project Source (program.dpk)

        HelperUnit                  Forms                ThirdPartyUnit

MyUtils MyConsts MyDownload                         TPShellShock  TPWhatever
```

How can I see this dependency tree of sorts?  I remember there being some feature like this in one of the newer Delphi versions, but I don't remember what it was called.  It may have been a plugin.

Any hints on how to do this would be great.  I started writing my own program to do it but I've already wasted like 3 hours and am still working on the parser for pas files.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076048/tools-to-generate-unit-dependencies-for-delphi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There also is a unit dependancy analyzer built inside of [GExperts](http://gexperts.org).  Look for the option labled "Project Dependencies".  This does work from an expert within Delphi against the currently loaded project.

[image: GExperts Project Dependancies]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a IDE integrated tool to do what you want, but you shall take a look at [Unit Dependency Analyzer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/articles/unit-dependencies.html), from ModelMaker.  The tool is free of charge.

Comment: This looks promising.  I'm playing around with it now.  If anyone else has suggestions please keep them coming though.

Comment: Looks interesting, but doesn't seem to be free anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You've got such graphs created in an automated manner by our Open Source documentation tool, called SynProject.

It uses internal a fork of PasDoc to parse the interface part of your project units, then extract the comments to get detailed info about each class/method/function/unit.
There are both unit dependencies diagrams and class hierarchy diagrams created from this data.

Then this information is merged into a whole technical documentation process, starting from Requirements, then Architecture, then Design, then Validation Plan, then Testing, then Release.

See http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SynProject

Answer (score 1):

Icarus is another tool to analyzing your "uses" dependencies; it has a great feature that lists units that don't need to be in your uses clauses.

http://www.peganza.com/

It's free.

Comment: +1 for this - I much prefer it over something that might mess up the IDE. Why the Delphi IDE can't tell you what is referencing a unit I'll never understand...a quick shortcut key to to show who "uses" this unit (within this project) would be fantastic!