# how to find all units of a delphi project

Tags: delphi, dcc32

how to get a list of all needed files for a delphi Project?

the files are in different directories, because some are used in different projects and must be transfered to a third party (ESCROW), but only the needed files shall be transferred and no others.

I tried in a batch "dcc32.exe --depends ..."  and the file project1.d is generated. that would help.

But if I add this option to dcc32.cfg, nothing happens (cfg-File seems not to be used).
Then I tried to rename dcc32.exe to dcc32.orig.exe and made an own dcc32.exe as an caller and put it into the Delphi-bin-Directory. (it makes a new command string from given ParamStrs(..), adds '--depends' and executs scc32.orig.exe).
Nothing happend.

Next, I commented out all lines in my own dcc32.exe so it does nothing (simple "begin end"), but wondering ... the project1.exe will still be compiled in the IDE (!!!) - I'm very confused about that.
Then I deleted my dcc32.exe and Delphi compile process says "...\bin\dcc32.exe not found.

It looks like as if Delphi would just search für the binary, but compiling with some other.

Is there any expert who knows, how the switch "--depends" can be added by default everytime Delphi compiles ?

Comment: Related: [Tools to generate unit dependencies for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3076048/576719) and [Tool that shows unit dependencies for Delphi 2010 or Delphi 7 program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904011/576719)

Comment: Sounds like you've made something of a mess of your Delphi installation. Note only do you have to identify the files, but presumably you need to make it possible for the third party to build. All the asserts, build scripts, etc. All this should be simple though. You just check out from your revision control into a new location and that should be it.

Comment: thank you for the link, but that's not what I'm lookuing for:

Comment: 1. Delphi definitivly KNOWS his files - otherwise it couldn't compile. and it has the feature build in with "-- depends". It would be best if I can activate this. 
2. I'm not a friend to install thousand of tools - each with it's own bugs, too many features I will never need - I only need the files.
3. Some tools are not free. The requirements are only for a special task in the moment but for many projects.
So, if someone has an idea how to give dcc32.exe the "--depends" flag that would be very great.

Comment: @Heffernan: thank you for your reply. the task is needed for Delphi 2007, but also for other delphi versions up to Tokio.

Comment: You could make the compiler write a map file which will then contain a list of all units used in the executable.