# Browsing source code when project codebase no full

Tags: delphi, ctags

I need 
understand how work some(5-6) exported function - for easy codejumping 
if code base is full I build it -and using browsing
but code base not full so compiling fail.

one road from many: add proxy unit wich include all proxed(thouse that implimentation I not have)(by hands or part auto) function,type,const,ets  THEN build as full - that path 1.

may be exist  tool that can linked all source and gen some output(html or other -not is defined) for jumping in code from using some identificator  to it definition and vica-versa?

UPD1. find Ctags,OpenCTags for Notepad++ . All is good, only one silly little mis: jump to interfase part of defenition , but I wonna to implimentation part (for C/C++ it like goto .h and not to .c/.cpp) any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about a pascal dependency analyzer, such as Peganza, discussed here:
[Tool that shows unit dependencies for Delphi 2010 or Delphi 7 program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904011/tool-that-shows-unit-dependencies-for-delphi-2010-or-delphi-7-program/2904397#2904397)

Comment: Good guess. Your Psychic muscle must be in shape. To me the last paragraph sounded more like a wish for ctrl-click or shft-up/down...